# Consider the source code below, where N is a constant declared with #define

Tags: c, assembly

```
 typedef int mat[n][n] //(size_t is defined as unsigned long, which is 8 bytes on x84-64 machines)

 int ele(mat a, size_t i, size_t j){
     return a[i][j];
 }
```

Suppose this generate the following assembly code:

```
   ele:
     salq $6, %rsi  // i= i<< 6 = 64i
     addq %rsi, %rdi // a= a + i = a +64i
     movl(%rdi, %rdx, 4), %eax // result = a + 4*j = a + 64i + 4j = a + 8*8*i + 8*1/2*j, since the size(t) = 8
```

The goal is find n = ____ ? I came up n = 8, you can see my steps in comments. However, the correct answer is n = 16. Can anyone help me find where is the mistake

Comment: `size_t` is the type of the indexes `i` and `j`. It's not the type of the array. The pointer arithmetic is being done using the type of the array. BTW, you will never, ever see a `1/2` being used in C pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The code shown won't compile — no definition of `n` and no semicolon at the end of the typedef.  It's hard to discuss broken code.  Please fix it!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is pseudo. And then it is "please recheck `sizeof (int)`"

Comment: @Gahlot Simply. `sizeof(int)` is **4** on x86-64 platforms. `64 / 4 ==` **`16`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = a + 64i + 4j = a + 8*8*i + 8*1/2*j, since the size(t) = 8
```

Your expansion here using 8 is wrong. Look at it this way.

```
a + 64i + 4j = a + 16*4i + 4j
```

Here `a` is base address of array. `i` is row selector. Each row contains 16 elements of size 4 (`sizeof int`) and you skip `i` such rows to get the base address of the `i`th row. Then you skip `4j` bytes (`j` ints) to reach the column you want.

I don't know what your end objective is, but if all you wanted to do was find `n`, then you could simply have done

```
sqrt(sizeof(mat)/sizeof(int))
```

assuming you are sure that it is an int array of square shape.

Comment: so basically, we just need to ignore "size_t is defined as unsigned long" ?

Comment: the size of `size_t` is reflected in the instruction itself. `salq` `addq` `movl` : These instructions specify that the address computation is happening using 8 bytes, but the actual address will always be independent of the size of the variable computing it. It depends only on target size.